# Save real time video to sd-card on android

Tags: video, save, real-time, rtsp, video-recording

i need to save real time video to SD card on my android device there is no code can do it i searched a lot but all codes that i found is not working
 i need to stream video from security cam using Real time streaming 
protocol
 i am using video view to stream video and it work successfully but can't record that to SD card

```
if(isNetworkStatusAvialable (getApplicationContext())) {

        // Execute StreamVideo AsyncTask

        // Create a progressbar
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        // Set progressbar title
        pDialog.setTitle("Android Video Streaming");
        // Set progressbar message
        pDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        // Show progressbar
        pDialog.show();
        try {
            // Start the MediaController
            MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                    MainActivity.this);
            mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
            // Get the URL from String VideoURL
            Uri video = Uri.parse(url);
            videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
            videoview.setVideoURI(video);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        videoview.requestFocus();
        videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            // Close the progress bar and play the video
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                videoview.start();





            }
        });
    } else {
        showMessage("internet is not avialable", buffer.toString());


    }
```